# Django Foreign Key and Forms

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am new to Django and was wondering if I could get some help.
I am trying to display a form in my template for a ToolCheckOut that will have two foreign keys that are referencing my two models. I keep receiving this error and have had no luck finding a solution. Error: "coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, long found" it is giving this error on my template for this line: "{{form.as_p}}"

I am using a mysql db that I had previously built for this project.

Form:

```
class ToolCheckoutCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ToolTransaction
        fields = [
            "ToolID",
            "Quantity",
            "PartyID",
            "CheckOutDate",
            "CheckInDate",
        ]
```

Models:

```
class Tool(models.Model):
    ToolID=models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key = True, unique=True, null=False)
    Quantity=models.IntegerField(null=False)
    Location=models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    CategoryID=models.IntegerField(null=True)
    Deleted=models.BooleanField(default=0)

    objects=models.Manager()

    class Meta:
            managed=True
            db_table='Tool'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.ToolID

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("ToolSearch:toolSearchResults", kwargs={"pk": self.ToolID})

class Party(models.Model):
    PartyID=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    FirstName=models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    LastName=models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    PhoneNumber=models.CharField(max_length=25, null=False)
    Organization=models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    Deleted=models.BooleanField(default=0)

    objects=models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        managed=True
        db_table='Party'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.PartyID

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("ToolSearch:borrowerUpdate", kwargs={"pk": self.PartyID})


class ToolTransaction(models.Model):
    CheckOutID=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ToolID=models.ForeignKey(Tool, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    PartyID=models.ForeignKey(Party, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Quantity=models.IntegerField(null=False)
    CheckOutDate=models.DateField(null=False)
    CheckInDate=models.DateField(null=True)
    Deleted=models.BooleanField(default=0)

    objects=models.Manager()

    class Meta: 
        managed=True
        db_table='ToolTransaction'
        ordering=('CheckOutID',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.CheckOutID) or u''

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("ToolSearch:toolCheckout", kwargs={"pk": self.CheckOutID})
```

Template:

```
<form method = 'POST' action=''>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <input type = 'submit' class = "button" value = 'Save'/>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__unicode__()` must always return a string or unicode. `Party.__unicode__()` does not. To fix, convert the returned value explicitly to string: `return str(self.PartyID)`

Comment: Thank you so much. I updated my Party model return, to a string and everything is working now. You are my hero!

Answer (score 0):

Add method like this.

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return u"%i" % self.CheckOutID
```

The documentation says:

The **unicode**() method is called whenever you call unicode() on an object. Since Django's database backends will return Unicode strings in your model's attributes, you would normally want to write a **unicode**() method for your model.

Comment: ToolTransatction model already has a `__unicode__` method, that returns self.CheckOutID converted to string.